# TSQL left join UPDATE by select appropriate single value

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, left-join

To simplify things, there are two tables 'trades' and 'rates'.

`trades.userid` and `rates.fee` are connected through `trades.rateid` = `rates.rateid`

Problem is SELECT doesn't return uniquely values, but all possible of them.

```
SELECT r.fee
FROM rates AS r
LEFT JOIN trades AS t
ON r.rateid = t.rateid
WHERE t.userid=(somevalue)
```

`DISTINCT` or `TOP 1` couldn't be an an option here due to messy ordering. Ordering is not needed here.

How to select right and uniquely?

I just want to SELECT appropriate `rates.fee` by given `trades.rateid` of some `trades.userid`

```
trades
------
userid rateid total
101    1      
101    1
101    2
101    1

rates
-----
rateid fee
1      0.90
2      0.80
3      0.70

UPDATE trades
    SET total = (someformula) * (above SELECT query goes here)
    WHERE userid = (somevalue)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to find the sum of the fees per user, or just unique fees per user? Try adding `GROUP BY t.userid, r.fee` for unique fees per user, or change it to `SELECT SUM(r.fee) ... GROUP BY t.userid` to sum the fees by user. Maybe you could so some sample content in both tables, and the results that you are expecting?

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer: The OP said `TOP 1` wasn't an option.

Comment: If there's a *given* `trades.rateid` then shouldn't your `WHERE` clause include something like `…AND t.rateid = (somevalue)`?

Comment: Perhaps if you could add a "given these records ... I expect these results ..." section, as it's hard to understand what you want.

Comment: Updated my question. I'm sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's only one rate for a particular trade, you can use the `update ... from` T-SQL construct:

```
UPDATE  t
SET     total = (someformula) * r.fee
FROM    trades AS t
JOIN    rates AS r
ON      r.rateid = t.rateid
WHERE   t.userid = (somevalue)
```

If `rateid` does not uniquely identify a rate, you should edit the question to clarify which rate should be picked.

Comment: Thank you, it works! This is really should be simple. I probably went complex a bit.